# How to create mean values by Day?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with values like this

```
Day Humidity Temperature
22/10/2020 59.3 21.1
22/10/2020 55.2 21.1
22/10/2020 59.2 21.1
```

and I would like to sort the values by Day. How can I achieve this using python? My code so far is below:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test_data.txt',
                 names=["Day", "Humidity", "Temperature"],
                 header=None)

df[['Day', 'Humidity']] = df["Day"].str.split(" ", 1, expand=True)
df[['Humidity', 'Temperature']] = df["Humidity"].str.split(" ", 1, expand=True)

df['Day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Day'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

The final result should be only one Humidity value per day. The same goes for Temperature.

Answer (score 0):

`df.groupby("Day").mean()`

The `groupby` operation allows you to group all values of "day" (for example) by a single value. The result is an "GroupBy" object, which you can apply several methods over - like "mean" to create a scalar of the average of all

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pandas `.groupby` operation like this:

```
df.groupby("Day")
```